# Performing firestore query in renderItem of FlatList to pass data to return Child

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

this is a school project and I have been stuck on a bug for more than 12 hours...

The context is user accepts a chat request from the sender and upon doing so, a new chat 'room' is created and shown when i go back to the **Chats** tab. All these are done in a `TabNavigator`.

My expected result is to dynamically/automatically load the **ChatItem** in the **Chats** tab (i.e. these ChatItems live in a `FlatList`) when I as a user accepts the incoming chat requests.

The problem is that I am trying to get the sender's data from `firestore` but I keep getting undefined for its data. My initial load for the app gets all users data from `firestore` and loads up the Redux store.

Flow:
Sender sends chat request -> Updates `firestore` and the changes are being listened to -> Receiver sees a new chat request (this works) -> Accepts -> New chat 'room' created for sender and receiver (should show automatically)

Ways I have tried to not get an undefined sender:

1. Accepting a chat request, updates `firestore` and then Redux store. Retrieve all users data from 'supposedly' updated Redux store. But it's undefined
2. Wrote a listener to listen for changes in the `users` collection in `firestore` but it's 1 step slower when rendering the items in the FlatList and I get undefined sender's data
3. Wrote conditional checks to check if sender's data is undefined, if yes, perform a DIRECT `firestore` query to get the sender's data from the `users` collection. But still I get undefined.

I suspect all these is due to the FlatList re-rendering again but I'm not exactly sure how to control it.

I did specify a state for the prop `extraData` in the `FlatList`.

I have exhausted all ways possible, did all research, and I'm dead flat exhausted.

I appreciate any help please, thank you so much.

Here is the `ChatsOverviewScreen`, cleaned up unnecessary codes:

```js
const ChatsOverviewScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const currentUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  const userData = useSelector(state => state.user.userData);
  // const usersData = useSelector(state => state.users.usersData);
  const [initial, setInitial] = useState(true);
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  const [chatsLatestMsg, setChatsLatestMsg] = useState([]);
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);

  // To listen for any update in Users collection
  // and then update usersData state
  useEffect(() => {
    const usersDataListener = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        let data = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          if (doc.id !== currentUid) {
            data.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
          }
        });

        setUsersData(data);
      });

    return () => usersDataListener();
  }, []);

  // To listen for any chat created for current user
  useEffect(() => {
    const chatsListener = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const latestChats = querySnapshot.data().chats;
        setChats(latestChats);
      });

    return () => chatsListener();
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   getUsers();
  // }, [chats]);

  // const getUsers = async () => {
  //   const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').get();

  //   let temp_users = [];

  //   querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
  //     if (currentUid !== doc.id) {
  //       temp_users.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
  //     }
  //   });

  //   setUsersData(temp_users);
  // };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.parentContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={chats}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          let peer;
          peer = usersData.filter(data => data.chats.includes(item))[0];
          let latestChat =
            chatsLatestMsg.length > 0
              ? chatsLatestMsg.filter(data => data.chatId === item)[0]
              : {};

          // console.log('before condition', peer);

          // if (peer === undefined) {
          // firebase
          //   .firestore()
          //   .collection('users')
          //   .where('chats', 'array-contains', item)
          //   .get()
          //   .then(querySnapshot => {
          //     let data = [];

          //     querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          //       if (doc.id !== currentUid) {
          //         data.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
          //       }
          //     });

          //     peer = data.filter(user => user.chats.includes(item))[0];

          //     console.log('undefined', peer);

          //     return (
          //       <ChatItem
          //         key={item}
          //         currentUid={userData.id}
          //         latestChat={latestChat}
          //         chatId={item}
          //         peer={peer}
          //         onPress={navigateChat}
          //       />
          //     );
          //   });
          // }

          console.log('!undefined', peer);

          return (
            <ChatItem
              key={item}
              currentUid={userData.id}
              latestChat={latestChat}
              chatId={item}
              peer={peer} // I keep getting undefined peer right here!
              onPress={navigateChat}
            />
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        extraData={chats}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

And finally, the `ChatItem`:

```js
const ChatItem = ({ peer, currentUid, chatId, onPress, latestChat }) => {
  let message = '',
    timestamp = '',
    id = '';

  if (latestChat.latestMessage !== undefined) {
    message = latestChat.latestMessage.message;
    timestamp = latestChat.latestMessage.timestamp;
    id = latestChat.latestMessage.id;
  }

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={styles.cardContainer}
      onPress={() =>
        onPress({
          peerData: peer,
          chatId: chatId,
          id: peer.id,
          name: peer.name,
          imagePath: peer.imagePath
        })
      }
    >
      <Layout style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        {peer.imagePath.length > 0 ? (
          <Image source={{ uri: peer.imagePath }} style={styles.avatar} />
        ) : (
          <UserAvatar name={peer.name} size={50} fontSize={22} />
        )}
      </Layout>
      <Layout style={styles.detailsContainer}>
        <Layout style={styles.topChatContainer}>
          <Layout style={styles.nameContainer}>
            <Text category='h6' style={styles.name}>
              {peer.name}
            </Text>
          </Layout>
          <Layout style={styles.timeContainer}>
            {timestamp.length > 0 && (
              <Text>{dayjs(timestamp).format('h:mm A')}</Text>
            )}
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
        <Layout style={styles.bottomChatContainer}>
          {message.length > 0 ? (
            <Text numberOfLines={1}>
              {currentUid === id ? `You: ${message}` : message}
            </Text>
          ) : (
            <Text>Click on here to start a conversation!</Text>
          )}
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If my eyes do not lie, I cant find anything related to redux. Did you connect your functional component to redux?

Also do you get the data from firestore in general? Just making sure

UPDATE:
If you do get the data from firestore and you have the data in redux the do the conditional rendering.

```js
return(
     <>
    {
       chatData.length > 0 ?
       <FlatList .../> :
       <ActivityIndicator .../> // It is the spinner
    }
    </>

)
```

Make sure to re-render the screen.

Comment: i previously had issues passing data from the redux store (filtering usersData) to the ChatItem. yes i get data when i print the usersData in useEffect. yes i do get data too! the whole issue is, i'm not getting the data i need 'fast' enough for ChatItem. sorry these codes above are quite a mess. i redid it. this above is just a little context of what's happening. quite messy, i apologise

Comment: It may have some bugs. May be you need to also use state booleans that would allow to re-render the screen. Anyway, conditional rendering is the key I think

Comment: To be honest, i would prefer working from here on out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135388/renderitem-not-rendering-when-dynamically-getting-data-from-firestore . the code above in my question is not exactly sustainable. i relied on redux and firestore and i got into a huge mess. would you mind taking this somewhere else to chat?

Comment: I would rather keep the convos in stackoverflow. If you still have troubles with code just keep them posted in that link. I will try to help as much as I can

Comment: np danny! i understand. yes i'm just trying to work from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135388/renderitem-not-rendering-when-dynamically-getting-data-from-firestore and making use of 2 hooks - `useState`, `useEffect`. will update you again! it's 308am here.. i'm half dead lol. EDIT: think im going to head to bed first, extremely exhausted.