# RenderItem not rendering when dynamically getting data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, flatlist

A ChatsOverview screen contains a FlatList that renders ChatItems. The FlatList's `data` prop is an array of chatIds. These ids will be used in a `firestore` query to get a document with data in it required by the ChatItem.

My issue is that the ChatItem is not getting the returned data from the `firestore` query whereas when i logged the return data from `get()` i get the data that i require.

I have tried creating a separate function to render the ChatItem and this function is async, to try and wait for `firestore` to return the data but to no avail..

The FlatList ought to re-render everytime the user is being added to a chat (chatIds i.e. the chatIdsListener).

I made some remarks in the code to show where it's printing/data is showing as expected.

ChatsOverviewScreen:

```js
const ChatsOverviewScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const currentUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  const [chatIds, setChatIds] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const chatIdsListener = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(currentUid)
      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        setChatIds(querySnapshot.data().chats);
      });

    return () => chatIdsListener();
  }, []);

  const renderChatItem = async chatId => {
    const querySnapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('chats')
      .where('chatId', '==', chatId)
      .get();

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      if (doc.id === chatId) {
        console.log('rendering chatItem', doc.data());

        return (
          <ChatItem
            key={chatId}
            chatData={doc.data()}
            currentUid={currentUid}
          />
        );
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.parentContainer}>
      <Layout style={styles.chatsContainer}>
        {chatIds.length > 0 ? (
          <FlatList
            data={chatIds}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('chats')
                .where('chatId', '==', chatId)
                .get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {
                  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    if (doc.id === item) {
                      console.log('rendering chatItem', doc.data()); // logs here

                      return (
                        <ChatItem // nothing being logged here for 'chatData'
                          key={item}
                          chatData={doc.data()}
                          currentUid={currentUid}
                        />
                      );
                    }
                  });
                });
              // renderChatItem(item);
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item}
            extraData={chatIds}
          />
        ) : (
          <Layout style={styles.emptyContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.emptyText}>
              {`Sorry, we can't find any chats.\nHead to the Team Up screen to get started!`}
            </Text>
          </Layout>
        )}
      </Layout>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

ChatItem:

```js
const ChatItem = ({ chatData, currentUid, onPress }) => {
  const { name, imagePath } = chatData.participants.filter(
    user => user.id !== currentUid
  )[0];

  console.log(name, imagePath); // not printing anything

  let message = '',
    timestamp = '',
    id = '';

  if (chatData.latestMessage !== undefined) {
    message = chatData.latestMessage.message;
    timestamp = chatData.latestMessage.timestamp;
    id = chatData.latestMessage.id;
  }

  return (
    <Pressable style={styles.cardContainer} onPress={() => onPress({})}>
      <Layout style={styles.avatarContainer}>
        {imagePath.length > 0 ? (
          <Image source={{ uri: imagePath }} style={styles.avatar} />
        ) : (
          <UserAvatar name={name} size={50} fontSize={22} />
        )}
      </Layout>
      <Layout style={styles.detailsContainer}>
        <Layout style={styles.topChatContainer}>
          <Layout style={styles.nameContainer}>
            <Text category='h6' style={styles.name}>
              {name}
            </Text>
          </Layout>
          <Layout style={styles.timeContainer}>
            {timestamp.length > 0 && (
              <Text>{dayjs(timestamp).format('h:mm A')}</Text>
            )}
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
        <Layout style={styles.bottomChatContainer}>
          {message.length > 0 ? (
            <Text numberOfLines={1}>
              {currentUid === id ? `You: ${message}` : message}
            </Text>
          ) : (
            <Text>Click on here to start a conversation!</Text>
          )}
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </Pressable>
  );
};
```

I appreciate any inputs, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, renderItem property is just for rendering the UI. It is not a great idea to have async tasks there. I would suggest filtering the data in  hooks an then pass the filtered data into renderItem

Comment: thanks for your input! yes, i have tried what you've suggested but i'm struggling with how to properly get the latest state in the redux store. i asked a question yesterday when the codes for the ChatsOverviewScreen was way longer and after being stuck for over 12 hours i just decided to redo the same screen today. if you could please look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119939/performing-firestore-query-in-renderitem-of-flatlist-to-pass-data-to-return-chil